# Why is my model so dark?

Tags: rendering, texturing, normal-map

I'm working on texturing my model and have been previewing the render. I have a light in my scene but my model is really dark.[image]

Here are my nodes for the material.[image]Am I doing something wrong? (I'm using cycles btw) 
[image]

Comment: is your light strong enough? have you tried with another object?

Comment: Using a cube beside my mesh it still is just as dark. I have a sun right beside it though.

Comment: It looks like your bump mapping is not proper. Your output of image texture(normal map) node which is yellow coloured is connected input of bump mapping which is purple coloured and this is not good. Try replacing the Bump Mapping node with Normal Map node and also try recalculating the normals.

Comment: At the start of the question I pointed out that I have a light in my scene but it isn't doing anything to my model

Comment: yes it can be the bump, perhaps try to put your image output in the Height input, you can also share your file

Comment: It looks like flipped normals.

Answer (score 2):

The Normal Map Image node was plugged into the wrong input. It was in normal but height appears to have fixed it. Thanks to moonboots2 for the answer.